# Как убрать эффект клика в десктоп меню, оставить лишь hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мучаюсь с меню уже неделю) Уже хочу оставить так как есть, но исправить одну проблему. В десктопной версии нужно чтобы работал только ховер, а у меня из-за адаптива стал работать еще и клик) И есть бага, что если один раз по меню кликнуть, то по ховеру оно уже не открывается.
Вообщем как в декстопной версии оставить hover, а клик убрать, но чтобы в адаптиве все работало так же.

```js
$('.menu__header-btn').on('click', function(){
  $('.menu__header-list').slideToggle();
});

$('.drop__down-menu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).children('.drop__down-list').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.header__menu-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 80px;
}
 .menu__header {
  max-width: 750px;
}
 .menu__header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
 .menu__header li + li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
 .menu__header a {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}
 .menu__header a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
 .drop__down-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
 .drop__down-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  left: 0;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px 0px rgba(82, 85, 90, 0.2);
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
 .drop__down-list li {
  width: 100%;
}
 .drop__down-list li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
 .drop__down-list li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
 .drop__down-list li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
 .drop__down-menu:hover .drop__down-list {
  display: block;
}
 @media (max-width: 520px) {
  .menu__header-list {
   left: 0;
   top: 56px;
 }
  .menu__header-list li {
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
 }
  .menu__header-list li a {
   display: block;
 }
  .menu__header li + li {
   margin-left: 0;
 }
  .drop__down-list {
   width: 100%;
 }
  .header__menu-inner {
   min-height: 55px;
 }
  .drop__down-list {
   padding: 0 12px;
   top: 40px;
 }
  .drop__down-menu.link__mega-menu {
   display: none;
 }
  .drop__down-menu:hover .drop__down-list {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__menu">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="header__menu-inner">

            <nav class="menu__header">
              <div class="menu__header-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </div>
              <ul class="menu__header-list">
                <li class="drop__down-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">Home</a>
                  <ul class="drop__down-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Home One Multi User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Two Single User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Three Product</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="drop__down-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">All products</a>
                  <ul class="drop__down-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Recent Items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular Items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Featured Items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Free Templates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Follow Feed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Top Authors</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="drop__down-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">Wordpress</a>
                  <ul class="drop__down-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Popular Items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admin Templates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog / Magazine / News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Corporate Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resume Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Landing Pages</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Festures</a></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </header>


    
    <!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я так понял декстопная версия у вас начинается с 521 пикселей и больше ? просто поставить условие (сейчас напишу)

Answer (score 1):

исходя из `@media (max-width: 520px)`  ниже написал условие проверки размера окна (клики только 520 и меньше пикселей)

```
if ($(window).width() < 521) {
   $('.menu__header-btn').on('click', function(){
       $('.menu__header-list').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.drop__down-menu').on('click', function(){
       $(this).children('.drop__down-list').slideToggle();
    });
}
```